# Latex Javadoc generation

Tags: java, latex, javadoc

Is there a way to generate a latex document from my java sourcefile's documentation?
I don't want to include LaTeX Elements in my documentation comments, I simply want to create LaTeX files instead of HTML.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to write LaTeX in your Javadoc, or to produce a LaTeX document from your javadoc html website ? For the first, I think Harry solution fit your need. For the second ...

Comment: They mention http://java.net/projects/texdoclet/, but how do I use/install it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Texdoclet](http://java.net/projects/texdoclet/) seems to be what you need. As for how to use it: [just like any other doclet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#doclet).

Comment: Do you know the class I have to specify for the option?

Comment: @Konstantin: no, but it should be easy to find if you look inside the JAR.

Comment: It does't break, but all I get are html files. `javadoc -d out -docletpath /home/konne/Downloads/texdoclet.jar *`

Comment: @Konstantin: you have to use both the -doclet and the -docletpath options. The first is to tell javadoc which doclet class to use, the second tells it where to find that class.

Comment: Thanks it is kind of working. It tells me `! LaTeX Error: Environment texdocclass undefined.`. But I guess you don't know how to solve this.

Comment: @Konstantin: no, sorry. It seems to be a very badly documented project.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to Texdoclet is the [`ltxdoclet`](https://github.com/ePaul/ltxdoclet) I created.

I think the main difference is that it also includes the source code, not only the Javadoc comments, though you can switch this off.

It is not very well documented on the github site - just download the code and do `ant pdfdoku` for an example output (`ant latexdoku` if you only want the LaTeX files). (It is documented in german, though.)

I really should add a readme file there.

---

For now, here is the [jar file](http://epaul.github.com/ltxdoclet/downloads/ltxdoclet.jar) - download it somewhere, and then use

```
 javadoc -docletpath ltxdoclet.jar -doclet de.dclj.paul.ltxdoclet.DocletStart -help
```

to see a list of options available. (This will be in german, if you have no english locale. Prefix it with "LC_ALL=en_US" or similar on bash to get the english version, or have a look at [help_en.txt](https://github.com/ePaul/ltxdoclet/blob/master/src/de/dclj/paul/ltxdoclet/help_en.txt) instead if you don't know german.)

I'm working on a webpage with some more documentation, but I'm not sure when it will be ready.

---

Now we have a [webpage](http://epaul.github.com/ltxdoclet/), too. It links the jar file, and also as an example the [javadocs when applied to itself](http://epaul.github.com/ltxdoclet/downloads/ltxdoclet-javadoc.pdf).

Comment: @Konstantin: I uploaded a jar file for you.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann I can't seem to generate my documentation in English, I've tried `LC_ALL=en_US javadoc...` was that not what you meant?

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore: 
javadoc: error - Class de.dclj.paul.ltxdoclet.DocletStart is not a valid doclet.
Note: As of JDK 13, the com.sun.javadoc API is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to rely on any doclet dependency, but rather on a javascript one, you can just add the following javadoc param:

```
-header "<script type='text/javascript' src='http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'></script>"
```

and simply use clean latex inside your comments such as `\(\sum_i a_i\)` or `\[\sum_i a_i\]`